# Filtering the directory out with Devel::Cover

Tags: perl, devel-cover

I wanted to get coverage of my Perl based application in CentOS with apache web server, and went for the [`Devel::Cover`](http://metacpan.org/pod/Devel::Cover) to get it done. After some initial struggles, I got it installed. Since the `PERL5OPT` env variable did not help me in getting the coverage, I tried to include `use Devel::Cover` inside the code (I know it's a bad idea, but it serves my purpose) . The `cover_db` is generating its run/structures after I restart the webserver, but the data seems to be having transactions done with the CPAN generic modules as well, which reduce the total coverage score.

For example: if I use a single method from `Net::FTP`, it reduces the total score by considering the total number of lines in that module. Likewise for all the modules from CPAN.

What I need is the ability to select the files from a specific directory for coverage and ignore all the rest. From the description, it seems the `+inc` and `-inc` options are designed for this, but when I try to use them, I get the following error

> `Unknown option: inc`

I would like to know couple of things.

1. After `cover_db` is updated with the transactions, is it possible to filter out from it using `cover -options`  during generation of report?
2. Is there any other way I could get the coverage of only specific paths?

Appreciate the response.

Comment: `Otherwise, if it is in one of the inc directories, it won't be included.`. Try `+/-select`.

Comment: I did not understand . Did you mean @INC?